# Visual Studio only has .NET 4 templates available

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I create a .NET project Visual Studio only gives me .NET 4 supported templates

[image]

I've tried re-installing Visual Studio and .NET as well as updating and modifying the installations.

I'm using the latest version of .NET and Visual Studio.

This the only web application I can find out of the options:

[image]

Here is my installation setup:

Only one is selected which is visible in the image

[image]

I've also selected the extra options for templates.

[image]

Comment: Check the _.NET desktop development_ workload to install it.

Comment: Oh really even though I only need web development templates?

Comment: *"I'm using the latest version of .NET and Visual Studio."* Which version of Visual Studio is it?

Comment: Give it a try. If it doesn't work, you can uninstall it, but I believe that selecting a workload just pre-selects the necessary _Individual Components_. Apparently, you haven't selected/installed the ones you need. Of course, it's possible that you just didn't select the appropriate project template. _.NETFramework_ (ie: 4.7.2, 4.8) has a different project template than _.NET_ (ie: 6, 7, 8)

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much I'll try it out

Comment: Do you think it could be when I updated the path to .NET 8 that Visual Studio only has access to .NET 4 now? I updated the path because I had some errors saying .NET SDK could not be found